# How do I access the contents of an SVG element rendered in a USE tag?

Tags: javascript, svg

Let's say I have an SVG tag with a defs tag in there that defines a template.

```
<svg id="stage" height="2000" width="2800" text-rendering="optimizeLegibility">

    <defs>
        <g id="myTemplate">
          <text class="myText"><tspan></tspan></text>
        </g>
    </defs>      
</svg>
```

Then in JS, I am able to inject a  tag into my #stage SVG element, like this:

```
           var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var lns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
            var elem = document.createElementNS(ns, "use");
            elem.setAttribute("id","XXX");
            elem.setAttributeNS(lns, "xlink:href", "#node-template");
            elem.setAttributeNS(lns, "transform", "translate(700,250)");
            console.log(elem);
            elem.addEventListener("load", function() {
               alert("yay!"); 
            });

            document.querySelector("#stage").appendChild(elem);
```

The load event doesn't work at all. if I console.log elem, I just get this:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xlink:href="#node-template" xlink:transform="translate(700,250)"></use>
```

The template renders fine, but what I'm trying to do, is get into the rendered template we're calling in use.  The goal is to set the contents of the tspan inside #myText.

I've tried using the following code and setting a timeout to wait until after it's been rendered, but that gives me the same result.

```
setTimeout( function() {
            var used = document.querySelector("#XXX");
            console.log(used);
             }, 500);
```

Is there some magic selector I need to know to do this?

Comment: Given that #stage implies that the template is in the same file you can access it via getElementById("myTemplate") etc

Comment: Thanks Robert.  The problem is, I don't want to change the template.  I need to change the rendered instance of it so that I can modify the size and attributes.  I think changing the template will mean that all of them will change.

Comment: If you change what the <use> points to then all instances will change. There's no way round that. If you need to display different things don't use <use>

Comment: So it's not possible to access what is rendered by the <use> tag *after* rendering?

Comment: you can only access the template. If you want to modify instances use javascript and clone a template.

Comment: That's what I figured, but if I'm going that route, I might as well just render it dynamically, or keep the template inline or in shadowdom.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Hey,  I was able to get a partial solution using CSS variables.  It works with fill, but not text because pseudo-selectors are not yet supported in SVG tspan.  https://jsfiddle.net/8nqL199g/